# Interpolation with QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, kriging

Resulting map is not generated after performing following steps:

1. Add vector layer(shapefile of a country)
2. Add demlimited text layer(.csv file of values/variables)
3. Click on processing toolbox
4. Type "oridinary kriging" in search tab.
5. In the window opened: select> points, attribute>desirable,type of quality measure>0/1, block size>100(?),max distance> ?,Lag distance classes>?,skip>?, variogram model> a+b*x, output extent>?,cellsize>?
   and remaining options....

Help me for solving the question marks i.e (?)

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  That description should include every tool and every parameter value that you tried.

Comment: QGIS->Add Vector Layer->Add Delimited Text Layer->Processing Toolbox->Ordinary Kriging->Select layer for Kriging->Map Generated-> Symbology Tool.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.